# Use ngFor scoped variable as variable in ngClass for className

Tags: angular, dynamic, interpolation, ngfor

what i'm trying to achieve is to change class dynamically using the value of the ngFor scoped variable as the class of the label.Here's my code:

````
 <ul formArrayName="pokeTypes">
            <li [formGroup]="nestedForm" *ngFor="let type of this.createListOfTypes()|async; let i = index">
                <!-- add style!  -->
                <input type="checkBox" [id]='type' [value]="type" [formControlName]="type"
                    (change)="onCheckStateChange($event)">
                <label [for]="type" [ngClass]="{'{{type}}': pokeTypes.controls[0].get('type').value !== null }">{{type|titlecase}}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
```**strong text**
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ng class for this

`<label [for]="type" [ngClass]="{'{{type}}': pokeTypes.controls[0].get('type').value !== null }">{{type|titlecase}}</label>`

Instead you can toggle your class like so:

`class="{{ pokeTypes.controls[0].get('type').value !== null ? type : '' }}"`

Or something similar.